# Flutter BottomNavigationBar and advanced navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building an app with 3 items in the bottom navigation bar. When I change the tab, a different widget is rendering. So far, so good...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomTest extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new _BottomTestState();
}

class _BottomTestState extends State<BottomTest> {
  List<Widget> _pages;
  Widget _selectedContent;
  int _bottomIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _bottomIndex = 0;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _definePages();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bottom Navigation Test'),
      ),
      body: _selectedContent ?? _pages[_bottomIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  title: Text("Red")
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                  title: Text("Blue")
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.people),
                  title: Text("Green")
              )
            ],
            currentIndex: _bottomIndex,
            onTap: _onTabTapped,
        )
    );
  }

  _definePages() {
    _pages = [
      Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            _defineFloatingActionButton(),
          ])
      ),
      Container(color: Colors.blue),
      Container(color: Colors.green),
    ];
  }

  _defineFloatingActionButton() {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            //TODO: How to navigate to another page with still displaying the bottom navigation bar?
          }
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _bottomIndex = index;
      _selectedContent = _pages[index];
    });
  }
}

//POST
class Post extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new _PostState();
}

class _PostState extends State<Post> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      PostHeader(),
      Text('This is a post.') 
    ]);
  }
}

//POSTHEADER
class PostHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new _PostHeaderState();
}

class _PostHeaderState extends State<PostHeader> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Text('Author'),
      onTap: () {
        //TODO: This should navigate to another page but still displaying the bottom navigation bar, too.
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But I can't figure out a best practice for more advance navigation. There are 2 problems that I'm currently facing.

1. When tabbing the FloatingActionButton on the first page, I want to display a fourth page but the BottomNavigationBar still needs to be visible and operable.
2. Building a more complex app, I'm dealing with a handful of nested classes. So on my root page, there is a class "Post" and the post contains a class "PostHeader". In PostHeader, there is a ListTile with an onTap callback that should affect my _selectedContent. How do I define this callback? Passing it trough all the different classes didn't seem right.

I thought about defining it in my BottomTest.dart and passing it trough Post and PostTile but that doesn't seem like best practice to me, especially when talking about lots of required callbacks.

Thank you very, very much in advance!

Comment: Here is a blog you can read that talks about your problem 1, not sure about problem 2. it talks about some hacks to build dynamic routes using TabNavigator
https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the fourth page will be shown as any of the other three pages and since the button is in the first page, the fourth page will take the place of the first page and still signal the first bottom "red" field as active.

If that is the case you should create an independent widget for the first page that includes all the logic you need to show other content. Thus you avoid rebuilding the main layout, including the `BottomNavigationBar`.

You could use something along these lines, by using a `FirstPage` widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new BottomTest(),
    );
  }
}

class BottomTest extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new _BottomTestState();
}

class _BottomTestState extends State<BottomTest> {
  List<Widget> _pages;
  Widget _selectedContent;
  int _bottomIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _bottomIndex = 0;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _definePages();

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Bottom Navigation Test'),
        ),
        body: _selectedContent ?? _pages[_bottomIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add), title: Text("Red")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.location_on), title: Text("Blue")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.people), title: Text("Green"))
          ],
          currentIndex: _bottomIndex,
          onTap: _onTabTapped,
        ));
  }

  _definePages() {
    _pages = [
      FirstPage(),
      Container(color: Colors.blue),
      Container(color: Colors.green),
    ];
  }

  void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _bottomIndex = index;
      _selectedContent = _pages[index];
    });
  }
}

//POST
class Post extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new _PostState();
}

class _PostState extends State<Post> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[PostHeader(), Text('This is a post.')]);
  }
}

//POSTHEADER
class PostHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new _PostHeaderState();
}

class _PostHeaderState extends State<PostHeader> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Text('Author'),
      onTap: () {
        //TODO: This should navigate to another page but still displaying the bottom navigation bar, too.
      },
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {

  bool showFirst = true;

  _defineFloatingActionButton() {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: _onButtonPressed,
      ),
    );
  }

  _onButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      showFirst = !showFirst;
    });
  }

  _buildFirst() {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          _defineFloatingActionButton(),
        ]));
  }

  _buildFourth() {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          _defineFloatingActionButton(),
        ]));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return showFirst ? _buildFirst() : _buildFourth();
  }
}
```

For the second point, perhaps you should open another question so you keep two, more or less, unrelated matters in different answers.